# Add content editor in datasheet view

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, list-view, datasheet, classic-experience

I'm using SharePoint 2016 classic view.

I want to edit a Datasheet view on a library, like it's possible for "classic" views.

For example, I sometime add a content editor on some "AllItems" view to add some instructions/information for users.

I'd like to do the same on Datasheet view, but can't access the page on modification to add some content editor.

Does someone know if it's possible and how?

Comment: Are you able to open page in edit mode? When you click on "Add web part", you can select content editor web part from "Media and Content" section. Add screenshot of page in edit mode and what you see under "Media and Content" section, if possible.

Comment: On "All Items" view, I can open page in edit mode. Not on the datasheet view

Comment: Seems I involontary found the how to.  First I added a content editor on a created new view.  Then I created a new datasheet view, and it seems to keep the content editor for all the new view !

Comment: Great, glad it works for you now!

Comment: How can I mark this post as answered ?

Comment: You can add your own answer below with detailed steps how you solved this issue. You will be able to accept it as an answer after some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer completely unvoluntary.

I created a new view, which I modified in edit mode to add a content editor and defined it as default.
After that, I created a DataSheet view.
And when I switched between views, I saw the DataSheet view was having same content editor as the default view !
That was exactly what I wanted !

Regards.